# How to fix typos or misspelled strings?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to fix typos on my table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
  `project.dataset.keyword` AS
SELECT
  'John' AS Name,
  'Hisory' AS Course,
  84 AS Grade
UNION ALL
SELECT
  'David',
  'Math',
  95
UNION ALL
SELECT
  'Sean',
  'Hisory',
  100
UNION ALL
SELECT
  'Adam',
  'English',
  67
UNION ALL
SELECT
  'Morris',
  'Hisory',
  77
```

As you can observe, the string 'Hisory' is misspelled.
How can I replace 'Hisory' with the correct spelling of 'History', without doing it manually on each and every cell of this table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *update* the table:

```
update `project.dataset.keyword`
    set course = 'history'
    where course = 'hisory';
```